# How can I modify/add more segments to my hair?

Tags: hair

How can I modify/add more segments to my hair with the new hair system?

Answer (score 0):

Note: In Blender 3.5 you can only delete control points in *Edit* mode, but not yet add/extrude points or subdivide curve segments.

Use a *Geometry Nodes* modifier with a ***Resample Curve*** node to define the number of control points that you want to have. The *Count* input is the number of control points that you will get. Note that the modifier doesn't work interactively in *Edit* mode. Make sure you are in the ***Object mode***, then **apply the modifier**.

[image: hair curve with 7 control points]

Back in *Edit mode* you can see the new control points. Or check out the *Geometry Nodes spreadsheet* in the *Geometry Nodes* workspace.

[image: resampled curve]

In the *Asset Browser* there is also a pre-made utility asset called *Redistribute Curve Points* that smoothly re-distributes the control points. It is useful after you have used the *Snake Hook* brush.